# How to prevent double records without checking every value if exists

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I`m aware that if you would like to prevent double input data in you table you can check if the value exists by a simple query

```
SELECT `id` FROM TABLE WHERE `title` == 'test'
```

I'm also aware that PHP can't handle multiple SQL requests in 1 query, so for example:

```
SELECT `id` FROM TABLE WHERE `title` == 'test1'
SELECT `id` FROM TABLE WHERE `title` == 'test2'
SELECT `id` FROM TABLE WHERE `title` == 'test3'
```

So a solution would be to put `'test1'`, `'test2'` and `'test3'` into an array, loop it and perform the same query 3 times in a row.

But all I want to accomplish is to only insert a row if another row with the same data doesn't already exists. There should be a better way to do so than this approach.

```
// if (!$row_exists) {
INSERT INTO table_name (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a UNIQUE index for all the necessary columns. And MySQL won't allow duplicates for them.

Comment: @user2642959:  and don't bother making any checks before the `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `UNIQUE` constraint on the fields that are supposed to be unique:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD UNIQUE u_abc (a, b, c);
```

Then do an `INSERT IGNORE`:

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_name (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 2, 3) ;
```

This will insert nothing if a unicity constraint would be violated (ie. if the record already exists)

Answer (score 0):

Replace Into has been handy to me in the past. Hope it helps

```
Replace Into table_name (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 2, 3);
```

reference:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: Beware, this is implemented as an `INSERT` optionally preceded by a `DELETE` (if the records already exists). Mind the side effect. It also requires the existence of a `UNIQUE` index.

Answer (score 0):

SQL has very strong methods to manage the unique-ness of data in the array (prevent duplicates). I'd reccomend researching the functionality of the [`UNIQUE`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) constraint and primary keys, and see if they will help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a check in a single statement by using :

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1,value2,...);
```

And then perform the insert operations.